# Python - ModuleNotFoundError: No module named error in VSCode

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have the below python project structure where ModuleProject is the name of the root folder inside VSCODE -

```
ModuleProject
        -main.py
        -tests
            -test_main.py
```

Content inside main.py -

```
import pandas as pd


def hello():
    print(f"how are you")


hello()
```

Now, when i try to import main module in test_main using the command  `from main import hello` , i am getting the error  `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'main'`

As per some articles i also tried doing `from ..main import hello` but it also gave error `ImportError: attempted relative import with no known parent package`

Any idea, what i am doing wrong....

Comment: Looking at your directory tree, main.py isn't immediately in the same directory as test_main.py, most likely the problem here.
Also it might be useful to reference main as main.py

Comment: we never mention .py while importing the python module. Also, main is not in the same directory hence this is what i want to know how to refer it now

Comment: It's not possible to import from a parent directory this way. You could use sys.path method, but it's a bit tricky. Take a look there https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-import-from-parent-directory/